# Unable to get DIV to stick with SKROLLR

Tags: jquery, css, html, skrollr

I am trying to get a DIV to stick with the viewport on the scroll down, I have used the same code as the demo. but still no go. I am also using bootstrap with my site, as well as SCROLL-O-RAMA (which is abit unnecessary). here is my code:

```
 <style>
#hand-stick {
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding-top:10%;
text-align:center;
}
</style>

<div id="skrollr-body">
<div id="hand-stick" data-1700="top:100%;" data-2200="top:0%;" data-3000="display:block;"data-3700="top:-100%;display:none;>                                     <img src="images/slide3/thumbs-up.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I doubt Skrollr and Scrollorama are compatible. (do you mean SuperScrollorama? The former is just a demo.)

Comment: It looks like you are missing a `position: fixed` to lock the div in place.

Comment: yes sorry, I meant **SuperScroll-o-Rama**

Comment: ok, so place a fixed positioning on the `#hand-stick` rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an old example that should help

http://jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/1/

```
function fixDiv() {
    var $div = $("#navwrap");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) { 
        $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'width': '100%'}); 
    }
    else {
        $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto', 'width': '100%'});
    }
}

$("#navwrap").data("top", $("#navwrap").offset().top); // set original position on load
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```